# how to display text on the image which is on top of other background image in html 5?

Tags: html, css, image

i have a background image and on top of that a other image on which i want to display the text.i have the position of both background image and other image as absolute.i have checked from other websites that if you want to display a text on top of image ,you must set the position of image as relative and that of text as absolute,but in my case if i set position of image as relative in-spite  of absolute my whole background get disturbed.here is my image of website[i want to display my text on the circular picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnKNR.png)

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: @Paulie_D i have already tried doing that but the text is coming at the botttom of image not on the top.i have already told that i am finding problem with the position,as everywhere it is done with the position of image as relative whereas in my case it is absolute so i am just asking the alternative.

Comment: If you've tried something...you should add your code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `<figure>` tag set the `<figcaption>` position as the example below.

```
<figure>
  <img src="img.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock">
  <figcaption style="position: relative; top: -36px;"> 
    Text on the image
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```